# Removing trailing slash in Bash after curling?

Tags: bash, curl

Got a weird one here, Bash version is 4.25, CURL is 7.32

As far as I know this is runnable script (for you) via the terminal

```
 #!/bin/bash

  protocol='https://bing.com'
  location="$(curl -Is $protocol |awk '/Location/{print$2}')" #responds: https://www.bing.com/

    shopt -s extglob;

        echo "'${location}'" #echos: 'https://www.bing.com/
                             #but where's my trailing ' (quote) ????
                             #its completely gone.... ???


    location=$(echo ${location%%*(/)}) #should remove trailing slashes
                                       #but I believe that the missing
                                       #quote from above is causing trouble....


    shopt -u extglob

  echo $location; #should be: https://www.bing.com ???
```

I can't cut off my trailing slash, something is interfering, and I just can't figure it out??

Comment: So from `https://www.bing.com/` you can to get `https://www.bing.com`?

Comment: @fedorqui sorry I don't understand the question?

Comment: should this command change from `location=$(echo ${location%%*(/)}) ` to `location=${location%/*} `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever something's missing from the end of your line in an echo, immediately think "carriage return!". `echo "$location" | cat -v` will show `^M` at the end.

To remove the carriage return from the HTTP headers curl outputs, use `tr -d '\r'`:

```
location="$(curl -Is "$protocol" | tr -d '\r' | awk '/Location/{print$2}')"
```

Comment: Awesome answer, didn't know about cat -v. waiting to accept and plus 1